# >= git 1.7.1 - command to determine which files of directory are version controlled

Tags: git, version-control, directory, command

I would like to know whether there is a single command in >= git 1.7.1 that shows me what part of a directory is under version control. Please write from which version your solution works.

On 1.7.1 I can do a "git log -p " but that is rather cluttered as it shows all the patch info.

What I would like to have, is a list of files in the directory that are under version control and a list of files in the directory that are not. Ideally this information should be there by using one command.

What would be even nicer to have all the files there as well that do not show because I excluded them through .gitignore at some point.

Thank you.

Comment: `git check-ignore -v -n *` - although you might need a newer git version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

```
git ls-tree --name-only -r master
```

Here, `--name-only` returns only the name of the file relative to the repository root, `-r` recurses into any folders that may exist, and `master` is the name of the branch for which you want the files tracked by git. Find more on the [man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html).